Regex pattern to replace any occurrence of {...} with actual values
I am trying to create a method that will allow me to replace any occurrence of {....} string with some values.
Let me give you an example:
public const string ProductsApi = "/api/companies/{companyId:int}/stores/{storeKey}/products";

This is a minimal API endpoint. In this particular endpoint we have 2 values to be replaced (this is optional, can be 1+ values to replace). So if companyId = 55 and storeKey = "se2", this will be the result:
public const string ProductPathForHttpClient = "/api/companies/55/stores/se2/products";

To minimize possibility for mistakes, I would like to have a string extension method, let's call it Interpolate(...), to do this:
var productsPathForHttpClient = roductsApi.Interpolate(55, "se2");

So, Interpolate would find 1st occurrence of {..}, and replace it with 1st value, then 2nd occurrence, and so on...
I can do this by searching for { (start) and } (end) and then replace this string with value, and then search for next occurrence, etc.
I am wondering if this is possible with regex? Basically I am trying to minimize mistakes to API calls, by defining the API, and then replace any {..} with actual values for HttpClient path.

If the ... values are known up front (or can be generated at the last moment, consider scrapping the Regex, and using StringBuilder.Replace looping through a Dictionary<string,string> where the keys look like "{storeId}" (braces included) and the values are what you want to use as the storeId (or whatever). You're like to find it's easier to write, easier to read/understand/maintain, and it's likely faster to execute

Although Anton answer is correct, I will generalize it a little bit:
public static class TemplateHelper
{
    public static string Replace(string template, IDictionary<string, object> replacements, bool throwOnNotFound = false)
    {
        if (replacements == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replacements));
        if (template == null)
            return null;
        return TemplatePattern.Replace(template, x => OnMatch(x, replacements, throwOnNotFound));
    }

    private static string OnMatch(Match match, IDictionary<string, object> replacements, bool throwOnNotFound)
    {
        var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
        if (replacements.TryGetValue(name, out var value))
        {
            return value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
        
        if (throwOnNotFound)
        {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Variable name '{name}' not found in replacement list");
        }

        return match.Value;
    }

    private static readonly Regex TemplatePattern = new Regex(@"{(?<name>\w+)(?<type>:\w+)?}", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

And some tests/examples of usage:
[TestFixture]
public class TemplateHelperTests
{
    public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> GetTestCases()
    {
        yield return T(
            "/api/companies/{companyId:int}/stores/{storeKey}/products",
            "/api/companies/55/stores/se2/products",
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "companyId", 55 },
                { "storeKey", "se2" }
            }).SetName("simple");
        yield return T(
            "/api/companies/{companyId:int}/stores/{storeKey}/products",
            "/api/companies/55/stores/{storeKey}/products",
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "companyId", 55 }
            }).SetName("not_found");
        yield return T(
            "/api/companies/{companyId:int}/stores/{storeKey}/products",
            "/api/companies/55/stores/se2/products",
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "companyId", 55 },
                { "storeKey", "se2" },
                { "foo", "bar" }
            }).SetName("too_much");
    }

    private static TestCaseData T(string template, string expected, Dictionary<string, object> replacements)
    {
        return new TestCaseData(template, expected, replacements);
    }
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestCases))]
    public void Check(string template, string expected, Dictionary<string, object> replacements)
    {
        var actual = TemplateHelper.Replace(template, replacements);
        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }
}


Although your answer is asking more than I wanted, I will mark it as accepted, since it also offers a match in actual value. The downside is that it is much slower for it, and is more cumbersome to call. So, if performance is not a problem, this is probably a better way to go.

string ReplaceWithList(string input, List<string> replacements)
{
    int i = -1;
    string ReplaceOneMatch(Match match)
    {
        i++;
        return replacements[i];
    }

    const string pattern = @"{.*?}";
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceOneMatch));
}


I am gonna post my findings here from last night,just so others can see alternatives. Its similar to Anton's answer, but with a small validation improvement and compiled regex for faster execution:
static readonly Regex _varPattern = new Regex(@"{[\w:]+}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
public static string Interpolate(this string src, params object[] values)
{
    if (values.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("You must pass replacement values.");

    int index = 0;
    var result = _varPattern.Replace(src, m => values[index++].ToString() ?? string.Empty);

    if (index != values.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Number of passed values ({values.Length}) is not equal to number of matches ({index})");

    return result;
}

